# How do I enable text wrapping on all column headers?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpftoolkit, word-wrap

How does one enable text wrapping on all column headers of a `DataGrid`, without disabling the other default header functionality? Such as column resizing, sort direction indicator, etc which are needed.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 49):

Or don't bother with the primitives in the app.xaml file and do the following (my objects):

```
<DataGrid Name="WBdataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ColumnHeaderHeight="50" >
    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns> ...
```

Comment: This seems to have the unfortunate effect of removing some of the styling my table had previously had via Material Design in XAML.

Answer (score 24):

> I would like to enable text wrapping
>   on all column headers of my DataGrid,
>   without disabling the other default
>   header functionality

You need to add the following namespace to your **app.xaml** file:

```
xmlns:primitives="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Primitives;assembly=WPFToolkit"
```

and then add this  tag to **app.xaml**:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type primitives:DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This will add text-wrapping to the headers of all of your DataGrids throughout your WPF application.

While we're on the subject, if you just wanted to *center* the text of each of your DataGrid headers, you could do this using the following style instead:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type primitives:DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
</Style>
```

Yet I've seen *so many* WPF articles suggesting that you can only do this by adding TextWrapping or HorizontalAlignment on each DataGrid column *individually*:

```
<toolkit:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=TaxAmount}">
    <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate >
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="Tax Amount" Width="90" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
</toolkit:DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: Wow, you gave a good answer to a year-old question an hour before I looked for it.  +1

Comment: I do not know why, but I tried all your code but It did not center the text?

Comment: Fanastic solution. Just FYI, I had an existing ColumnHeaderStyle defined in a ResourceDictionary and simply pasted the Setter Property -to- Setter block into that. It worked like a charm and altered the appearance of all the datagrids that had that style, without requiring a reference to the primitives or WPF Toolkit.

Answer (score 17):

I added `&#x0a;` to the header text where I want the text to wrap. This is useful when you don't need to bind your header text to something

```
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="cAccountNumber" 
                    Header="Account&#x0a; Number" 
                    Width="80" 
                    Binding="{Binding Path=AccountNumber}" />
```

Comment: THANK YOU! - New to WPF from web technologies and this shouldn't be obnoxiously difficult with all these styles. Throw something inline. DONE!

Answer (score 10):

Instead of assigning the column name directly to the DataGridColumn.Header property, I created a TextBlock containing the column name, set the TextWrapping property of the TextBlock to "Wrap" and assigned the TextBlock to the DataGridColumn.Header property. This preserves the default header functionality.

Example:

```
<toolkit:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=MyProperty}">
    <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn.Header>
        <TextBlock Text="Something Longer" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    </toolkit:DataGridTextColumn.Header>
</toolkit:DataGridTextColumn>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a global `Style` for your column headers. Without any example mark-up I don't know the syntax, but it should look something like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type dg:ColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
</Style>
```

Since the `Style` is key-less, it will automatically be applied to all of your column headers. And styles will not override any locally set properties, so it won't "disable" any existing header functionality.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I have not been able to get this approach to work. However I did find that I can get my desired result if instead of assigning a string to the DataGridColumn.Header property, I create a TextBlock containing my string and set the TextWrapping property of the text block to "Wrap".

Comment: what about wrapping the content no header?