# WPF DataGrid Cell Text Wrapping - set to NoWrap (False)

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, word-wrap, datagridcell

How do I set the TextWrapping of every cell in a WPF DataGrid to "NoWrap"?  I understand the Cell itself does not have a "TextWrapping" property, but I'd like to set the property on the control within the cell.

The DataGrid I am working with does not have columns defined explicitly, the result set it is displaying is dynamic.

I am looking for a solution similar to the answers provided in the links below.  However I do not want to explicitly override the cell style/template and define the control to be used.  Instead I would like to say, IF a TextBlock is being used, set its TextWrapping property to NoWrap.

[WPF toolkit datagrid cell text wrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503262/wpf-toolkit-datagrid-cell-text-wrapping)
[How do I enable text wrapping on all column headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289285/wpf-toolkit-datagrid-how-to-enable-text-wrapping-on-all-column-headers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the resources of your DataGrid, you can specify an alternative default style for TextBlocks. This should do what you require ("*IF a TextBlock is being used, set its TextWrapping property to NoWrap*"). This won't work if the TextBlocks explicitly specify a different style to be used.

```
<DataGrid ...>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="NoWrap"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    ...
</DataGrid>
```

(Untested, since I do not have Visual Studio available right now.)